# Cómo obtener el total a pagar de todos los registros de una tabla usando jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas tardes a toda la comunidad, estoy mostrando los datos de un formulario a una tabla al presionar un **botón(btnAgregarTabla)**, los datos se muestran correctamente en la tabla pero adicionalmente necesito calcular el total a pagar de todos los registros de esa tabla y visualizarlos en un **input**, y ahí está mi problema, no he podido calcular el **total a pagar**, intenté con un foreach y solo se crea un bucle infinito, espero alguien pueda ayudarme, gracias.
Comparto el código de mi javascript y html.

```
// esta funcion me permite agregar los valores del
    // formulario a la lista
    function AgregarLista() {
        var item = 0;
        $('#btnAgregarTabla').click(function () {
            item++;
            cliente = $('#id_cliente').val();
            codigo = $('#id_producto').select2('val');
            descripcion = $('#nombre_producto').val();
            precio = $('#precio').val();
            cantidad = $('#cantidad').val();
            subtotal = precio * cantidad;

            var fila = '<tr><td>' + item + '</td><td>' + cliente + '</td><td>' + codigo + '</td><td>' + descripcion + '</td><td>' + precio + '</td><td>' + cantidad + '</td><td>' + subtotal + '</td></tr>';
            var btn = document.createElement('tr');
            btn.innerHTML = fila;
            document.getElementById('dtVenta').appendChild(btn);
        });
    }

    // ESTE ES EL CODIGO DEL FORMULARIO Y LA TABLA
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5>Datos del cliente:</h5>
        <div class="form-group d-flex">
            <div class="col-md-6 d-flex">
                <input type="text" name="dni" id="dni" class="form-control" placeholder="dni cliente">
                <input type="button" id="btnBuscarCliente" value="Buscar" class="btn btn-outline-danger">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="hidden" name="id_cliente" id="id_cliente" value="">
                <input type="text" name="nombre_cliente" id="nombre_cliente" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Cliente" disabled>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h5>Datos del producto:</h5>
        <div class="form-group d-flex">
            <div class="col-md-6 d-flex">
                <!-- <input type="text" name="id_producto" id="id_producto" class="form-control" placeholder="codigo producto"> -->
                <select name="id_producto" id="id_producto" class="id_producto js-states form-control"></select>
                <input type="button" id="btnBuscarProducto" value="Buscar" class="btn btn-outline-danger">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="text" name="nombre_producto" id="nombre_producto" class="form-control" placeholder="Producto" disabled>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" name="precio" id="precio" class="form-control" placeholder="s/.0.00" disabled>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="number" name="stock" id="stock" class="form-control" placeholder="stock" disabled>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="number" name="cantidad" id="cantidad" value="1" class="form-control" placeholder="cantidad">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <table id="dtVenta" class="table mt-4" style="width: 100%;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nro.Venta</th>
                        <th>Cliente</th>
                        <th>Codigo</th>
                        <th>Descripcion</th>
                        <th>Precio</th>
                        <th>Cantidad</th>
                        <th>SubTotal</th>
                        <th>Acciones</th>
                    <tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <div class="row">
                <input type="button" id="btnCancelarVenta" value="Cancelar" class="btn btn-danger">
                <input type="button" id="btnGenerarVenta" value="Generar" class="btn btn-success mx-1">
                <div class="d-flex ml-auto">
                    <label for="" class="mx-2 mt-1">Total:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="total_pagar" id="total_pagar" class="form-control">
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

y si mejor declaras una variable en la cual almacenar al momento de agregar ya los vas sumando

```js
var item = 0;
var total = 0;
function AgregarLista() {        
    item++;
    cliente = $('#id_cliente').val();
    codigo = $('#id_producto').val();
    descripcion = $('#nombre_producto').val();
    precio = $('#precio').val();
    total = eval(total)+eval(precio);
    cantidad = $('#cantidad').val();
    subtotal = precio * cantidad;

    var fila = '<tr><td>' + item + '</td><td>' + cliente + '</td><td>' + codigo + '</td><td>' + descripcion + '</td><td>' + precio + '</td><td>' + cantidad + '</td><td>' + subtotal + '</td></tr>';
    var btn = document.createElement('tr');
    btn.innerHTML = fila;
    document.getElementById('dtVenta').appendChild(btn);
    $("#total_pagar").val(total);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-body">

        <h5>Datos del cliente:</h5>
        <div class="form-group d-flex">
            <div class="col-md-6 d-flex">
                <input type="text" name="dni" id="dni" class="form-control" placeholder="dni cliente">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="hidden" name="id_cliente" id="id_cliente" value="1">                
            </div>
        </div>
        <h5>Datos del producto:</h5>
        <div class="form-group d-flex">
            <div class="col-md-6 d-flex">
                <!-- <input type="text" name="id_producto" id="id_producto" class="form-control" placeholder="codigo producto"> -->
                <select name="id_producto" id="id_producto" class="id_producto js-states form-control">
                <option value="1">Opcion 1</option>
                </select>
                <input onclick="AgregarLista()" type="button" id="btnBuscarProducto" value="Agregar" class="btn btn-outline-danger">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="text" name="nombre_producto" id="nombre_producto" class="form-control" placeholder="Producto">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" name="precio" id="precio" class="form-control" placeholder="s/.0.00">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="number" name="stock" id="stock" class="form-control" placeholder="stock">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="number" name="cantidad" id="cantidad" value="1" class="form-control" placeholder="cantidad">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <table id="dtVenta" class="table mt-4" style="width: 100%;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nro.Venta</th>
                        <th>Cliente</th>
                        <th>Codigo</th>
                        <th>Descripcion</th>
                        <th>Precio</th>
                        <th>Cantidad</th>
                        <th>SubTotal</th>
                        <th>Acciones</th>
                    <tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <div class="row">
                <input type="button" id="btnCancelarVenta" value="Cancelar" class="btn btn-danger">
                <input type="button" id="btnGenerarVenta" value="Generar" class="btn btn-success mx-1">
                <div class="d-flex ml-auto">
                    <label for="" class="mx-2 mt-1">Total:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="total_pagar" id="total_pagar" class="form-control">
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: me funcionó correctamente con tu ejemplo, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Hice un ejemplo sencillo de lo que puedes utilizar, Primero creamos dos arreglos estos serán tus valores que insertas a la tabla, a cada `td` le agregue la clase `precio` para poder seleccionar con JS o jQuery el texto que sería el precio dentro de esos `td`, seleccionamos la clase con `document.getElementsByClassName('precio')` esto te devuelve un `HTMLCollection` de la etiqueta a la cual accedes por su atributo `class` o de la misma `etiqueta`, entonces hay que recorrerlo con un `for`, ya que lo recorremos guardo los valores en otro arreglo (hice esto porque intentando sumarlo dentro del for me sumaba sólo el ultimo valor que es 40+40 la verdad no sé por qué), despues podemos usar el método `reduce` que como su nombre lo indica reduce un arreglo a lo que le indiques, en este caso la suma de sus valores te da un solo resultado, espero me haya explicado, cualquier duda hazla saber.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

const precio = [20,10,15,40];
const producto = ['plato','escoba','shampoo','cepillo'];

let tabla = document.getElementById('body');

let contenido = '<tr>';
                 
for(let i = 0; i < precio.length; i++){
  
    contenido += `<tr><td>${producto[i]}</td>
    <td class="precio">${precio[i]}</td></tr>
                        `;
  
}

contenido += '</tr>';

tabla.innerHTML = contenido;


document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', calcular);


})



function calcular(){
 
 var tPrecio = document.getElementsByClassName('precio');
 

   let numeros = new Array();
    for(let x = 0 ; x < tPrecio.length; x++){
       numero = parseInt(tPrecio[x].innerText);
       numeros.push(numero);

    }

let suma = numeros.reduce((p,c)=>{

return p+c;
})
 console.log(suma);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="tabla">
<thead>
<th>Producto</th>
<th>Precio</th>
</thead>
<tbody id="body">

</tbody>
</table>


<button id="btn">Calcular total</button>
```